# Ajax request doesn't update dropdpwn menu after 2nd call

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am facing an issue the last days so I would like your help.

I have created a `jQuery` script in order to update an existing dropdown menu (setting disable or enable depending on returned results).The fact is the it works but only once.In all the next calls the update is the same as it was on the first call.

```
$('#date_input').change(function(){
    var date = document.getElementById('date_input').value;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "check_files.php",
        data: { "date": date },
        cache: false,
        async: false,
        success: function(results) {
            file_list = jQuery.parseJSON(results);
            jQuery.each(file_list, function(i, val) {
                // $("#city_input option[value='" + val + "']").remove();
                $("#city_input option[value='" + val + "']").attr('disabled', 'true');
            });
        }
    });
    $('#date_input').datepicker('hide');
});
```

Comment: If you're getting the same results back from multiple requests it sounds like you may be caching on the server, check your server side code. You should also remove `async: false` as it's horrendous practice to use it. If you check the console you'll even see warnings telling you not to use it.

Comment: What are you expecting to do with this:
$('#date_input').datepicker('hide');

Comment: Returned data are always right so php (in my case) works fine.The problem is that jQuery doesn't update dropdown after 1st call.Holds the result of the 1st call. This $('#date_input').datepicker('hide'); hides the calendar of datepicker.

Comment: Why are you mixing `$` and `jQuery` ? Try to be coherent in your code.

Comment: Can you observe the network calls in browser's tools, and check if the required parameter i.e. `date` has correct value each time?

Comment: Don't call this to fast. How long is the break between two calls?

Comment: `var date = document.getElementById('date_input').value;` => Are you sure to get the right value? You seem to use a javascript library so you maybe need to do something like `$('#date_input').datepicker('getDate');` to get the right value of your datepicker?

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand you the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line:

```
$("#city_input option").removeAttr('disabled');
```

before

```
jQuery.each(file_list, function(i, val) {
```

to reset last changes. If you miss this, no old disabled option will be enabled again

```
    success: function(results) {
        file_list = jQuery.parseJSON(results);
        $("#city_input option").removeAttr('disabled');
        jQuery.each(file_list, function(i, val) {
            // $("#city_input option[value='" + val + "']").remove();
            $("#city_input option[value='" + val + "']").attr('disabled', 'true');
        });
    }
```

Comment: I think it still won't solve the problem. He mentioned `In all the next calls the update is the same as it was on the first call`. So, resetting all the options won't help.

Comment: I think this is the answer!Thanks!Sorry @31piy.I didn't notice that.You are right!